# Calculating the Upper Bound on the Sphere Radius of Knotted Channel Surfaces

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, knot-theory, nonlinear-optimization

This question is motivated by trying to determine the upper bound on the thickness of a rope of fixed length (w.l.o.g. $2\pi$), with which a knot of given topology can be realized under the further condition that the ends of the rope can be smoothly connected.
In a mathematical setting, the rope who's ends are smoothly connected after knotting, can be modelled by a knotted channel surface with circular cross-sections of constant radius and, without self-penetrations.

What I would like to know, is:

- how can the restrictions on knot-topology and being free of self-intersection be incorporated into an optimization problem for maximizing the "rope-thickness"?
- do there already exist algorithms for solving those type of optimization problems?
- would a solution to the problem yield knot-invariants like the maximal number of self-contacts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jason Cantarella has studied this problem extensively,
and written [several papers](http://www.jasoncantarella.com/wordpress/papers/) on the topic.
See his [Octrope](http://www.jasoncantarella.com/wordpress/software/octrope/)
webpage:

> Octrope is a library for quickly finding the thickness or ropelength of polygonal knots.

---

[image: Trefoil]

          

<sup>(Image from a [Ridgerunner](http://www.jasoncantarella.com/movs/) minimization
animation for the trefoil, $3_1$.)</sup>

---

Comment: Good pointer, Joseph! My problem seems to be known as the tight knot problem.